# sorting pandas dataframes according to cut in python?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

if I use `pandas.cut` to generate bins labels like `[0.3, 0.5), ...`, how can I sort the dataframe according to these bins in ascending order? E.g. `[-0.4, -0.2)` should come before `[-0.2, 0.0)`, etc.  Example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randn(10)})
# bin according to cut
df["bins"] = pandas.cut(df.a, np.linspace(-2,2,6))
```

Now how can you sort df according to the labels generated by `cut` (the `df["bins"]` column)?

Comment: Could you not just sort column 'a' first? `df.sort(columns=['a'],inplace=True) df["bins"] = pd.cut(df.a, np.linspace(-2,2,6))` will then order it prior to applying the cut for the new 'bins' column

Comment: Or you could just sort 'a' after applying `cut` would achieve the same thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you sort df by column 'a' first then you don't need to sort the 'bins' column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randn(10)})
# for versions older than 0.17.0
df.sort(by=['a'],inplace=True)
# if running a newer version 0.17.0 or newer then you need
df.sort_values(by=['a'],inplace=True)
# bin according to cut
df["bins"] = pd.cut(df.a, np.linspace(-2,2,6))
df

Out[37]:
          a          bins
6 -1.273335    (-2, -1.2]
7 -0.604780  (-1.2, -0.4]
1 -0.467994  (-1.2, -0.4]
8  0.028114   (-0.4, 0.4]
9  0.032250   (-0.4, 0.4]
3  0.138368   (-0.4, 0.4]
0  0.541577    (0.4, 1.2]
5  0.838290    (0.4, 1.2]
2  1.171387    (0.4, 1.2]
4  1.770752      (1.2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas .17, the new way to sort is to use sort_values. The preferred solutions becomes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randn(10)})
df.sort_values('a',inplace=True)
# bin according to cut
df["bins"] = pd.cut(df.a, np.linspace(-2,2,6))
df
```